# Java8 Stream loop iteration

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Please anyone help me to do this in Java8 streamAPI,

```
for(ContactDto contact : contactList){
    for(ContactContactTypeDto contactType : contact.getContactTypes()){
        if(PRIMARY_CONTACT.equals(contactType.getIdContactTypeCode())){
            StringBuilder contactNameSB = new StringBuilder(contact.getFirstName());
            contactNameSB.append(" ");
            if(null!=contact.getMiddleName() && !contact.getMiddleName().isEmpty()){
                contactNameSB.append(contact.getMiddleName());
                contactNameSB.append(" ");
            }
            contactNameSB.append(contact.getLastName());

            contactName = contactNameSB.toString();
            contactEmail = contact.getEmailAddress();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried but I am reach only upto

```
contactList.stream()
    .filter(contact -> contact.getContactTypes()
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(contactType -> PRIMARY_CONTACT.equals(contactType.getIdContactTypeCode())));
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't quite make sense, you iterate the contacts but `contactEmail` and `contactName` will always be the last `ContactDto` in the loop because they're overwritten. Are you missing a `break`?

Comment: can you explain what should be result. what should perform using contactNameSB. i cant see there any usages of this code.

Comment: The result of your code is ignored, because you don't do anything with the `StringBuilder` after appending to it. What do you actually want to happen? For example, should all the matching contacts be collected or just the first?

Answer (score 4):

When code with java 8 streams get convoluted it is beneficial to create some additional types and methods. E.g.

A method to create a full name from it's parts (you don't need `StringBuilder` the compiler will use one in this case):

```
String createFullName(ContactDto contact) {
    String contactName = contact.getFirstName() + " ";
    if (null != contact.getMiddleName() && !contact.getMiddleName().isEmpty()) {
        contactName += contact.getMiddleName() + " ";
    }
    return contactName + contact.getLastName();
}
```

A class to hold the result, basically a pair of name and email (add constructor, getters etc):

```
class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String email;
}
```

And now the code becomes much simpler:

```
Optional<Contact> contact = contactList.stream()
        .filter(c -> c.getContactTypes()
                .stream()
                .map(ContactContactTypeDto::getIdContactTypeCode)
                .anyMatch(PRIMARY_CONTACT::equals))
        .findFirst()
        .map(c -> new Contact(createFullName(c), c.getEmailAddress()));
```

Extra code after what you have done is [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) which will returns an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) describing the first element of this stream, or an empty Optional if the stream is empty.

The last [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) will be applied on the resulting `Optional<ContactDTO>` if it's not empty to create a `Contact` or else return an empty `Optional<Contact>`.

Comment: Thanx.. This working fine but I am not suppose to create one more new class

Comment: In that case you could (ab)use [SimpleEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) or one of the `Pair` implementations in various libraries.

Answer (score 2):

It may make sense to use a `Stream` pipeline to obtain the single `ContactDto` from which you wish to extract details:

```
ContactDto contact =
    contactList.stream()
               .filter(c -> c.getContactTypes()
                             .stream()
                             .anyMatch(t->PRIMARY_CONTACT.equals(t.getIdContactTypeCode())))
               .findFirst()
               .orElse(null);
```

Then use that instance to assign the required values to your two variables:

```
if (contact != null) {
    StringBuilder contactNameSB = new StringBuilder(contact.getFirstName());
    contactNameSB.append(" ");
    if(null!=contact.getMiddleName() && !contact.getMiddleName().isEmpty()) {
        contactNameSB.append(contact.getMiddleName());
        contactNameSB.append(" ");
    }
    contactName = contactNameSB.toString();
    contactEmail = contact.getEmailAddress();
}
```

Note:

This will assign values based on the first matching `ContactDto` instance found.

Comment: Although it could be a train wreck, you could do it in one statement by wrapping the stream result in `Optional.ofNullable()` then putting the second part in a `.map()` then do something with it via `ifPresent()`.

Comment: @Bohemian yes, it can be done (you don't even need `Optional.ofNullable()`, `.findFirst()` already returns an `Optional`). I wouldn't apply `map` on the Optional, though, since you have to produce two outputs (one assigned to `contactName` and the other to `contactEmail`), so you'd have to put the entire second part in `ifPresent()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ContactDto> contactListWithPrimaryContact = contactList.stream()
                .filter(contact -> contact.getContactTypeDto().parallelStream()
                        .anyMatch(x -> x.getIdContactTypeCode().equals(PRIMARY_CONTACT)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

After getting all the contacts with primaryContact type, perform the operations you want further.

getting first contact with type as PRIMARY_CONTACT and assigning value to global variable, seems useless.

because what about the second contact in the list with the contactType as PRIMARY, as per the above solution, we are ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> listOfPrimaryEmailAddresses = contactList.stream()
                                                      .filter(primaryContactPredicate())
                                                      .map(ContactDto::getEmailAddress)
                                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());


List<String> primaryContactNamesList = contactList.stream()
                                                  .filter(primaryContactPredicate())
                                                  .map(ContactDto::getFullName)
                                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

private Predicate<ContactDto> primaryContactPredicate() {
        return contact -> contact.getContactTypes().stream().anyMatch(contactType -> PRIMARY_CONTACT.equals(contactType.getIdContactTypeCode()));
}
```

in ContactDto class add method for getFullName()

```
public String getFullName() {
        if (null != getMiddleName() && !getMiddleName().isEmpty()) {
            return getFirstName() + " " + getMiddleName() + " " + getLastName();
        }
        return getFirstName() + " " + getLastName();
    }
```